# Parallelizing mask process using geopandas to cookie cut a rasterio object

Tags: geopandas, rasterio, parallel-processing

I have a very large raster data and a shape file with 79,867 polygons. I want to efficiently extract statistics from the raster within each of the polygons. To do so, I have combined rasterio and geopandas. I first convert the shape into a geopandas dataframe. Then I iterate over each row of the dataframe and cookie cut the raster with each of the rows (as one-row geopandas dataframe), generate a numpy array and then I can get any stats I want with it (see code below). I save the stats into a dictionary and convert the final dictionary into a pandas DF.  This is a slow process, of course, because iterating over dataframe rows is naturally slow. One feature of my code below is that I have a provision to save partial results into a csv file and give me a progress report. My goal now is to parallelize this algorithm. I have been searching alternatives for that, and most of the suggestions include dividing the dataframe into chunks and process each chunk in a vectorized fashion in a different core. This can be done with multiprocessing pool and there is plenty of examples available. However, if I do that, I will lose (at least as far as my coding skills go) the ability to create progress reports and save partial results. In addition, because the cookie cut process is rather slow, I am not convinced that vectorizing it will show gains in speed, and I am not sure the geopandas dataframe will handle such a complex process well. So, my inclination is to retain the row by row processing and distribute the individual rows into different cores instead of partitioning the entire dataframe as suggested. I would like some advice on what is the best alternative to parallelize this process. Unfortunately, most examples I came across to parallelize pandas dataframe processes apply very simple functions, like x*x, which is far from being this case.

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.mask import mask
from time import time

StartTime = time()
geodf = gpd.read_file("data/polygon.shp")
statsDict = {}
with rio.open("data/raster.tif") as src:
    profile = src.profile
    n=0
    for gpd in geodf.itertuples():
        if n > 0 and n%5000 == 0:
            perc = 100*n/geodf.shape[0]
            print (int(perc), ' %', (time() - StartTime)/ 60, ' minutes')
            forecastFinish = round(((100 * (time() - StartTime)/perc)/3600), 1)
            print(' estimated time to finish: %s hrs' %forecastFinish)
            df = pd.DataFrame(statsDict.items(), columns=['feature_id', 'meanScore'])
            fileName = 'results/partial_' + str(n) + '.csv'
            df.to_csv(fileName, index=False)
            statsDict = {}
        feature_id = (gpd.__getattribute__('feature_id'))
        polygon = gpd.__getattribute__('geometry')
        IterPolygon = [gpd.__getattribute__('geometry')]
        mask_feature_id, mask_feature_id_Transform = mask(xscores, \
            IterPolygon, invert=False)
        flat_mask_feature_id = np.ravel(mask_feature_id)
        meanScore = np.mean(convertNpArrayIntoPreppedList(flat_mask_feature_id))
        statsDict[feature_id] = meanScore
        n+=1

df = pd.DataFrame(statsDict.items(), columns=['feature_id', 'meanScore'])
fileName = 'results/final' + '.csv'
df.to_csv(fileName, index=False)
```

Comment: Doing it in chunks is a solid approach.  You can send the results from processing each of the chunks back to the main process where it can report progress (based on the number of chunks completed) and write to the CSV

Comment: Yes, I thought about that. However, If I do that, one caveat is that I would like to split the dataframe into a number of chunks much greater than the number of cores, which implies some chunks will remain in queue. I couldn' t find a good alternative for that yet.

Comment: That's perfectly fine, you can use something like [concurrent.futures](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html) to manage a large number of tasks running in a smaller number of threads/processes

Comment: I think this is the proper way to parallelize. Thanks. However, vectorizing the mask to use each row as a different polygon is not trivial. There is not a lot of documentation out there. I guess this has lead my early decision to iterate over rows instead of applying the function to the dataframe.

Comment: I successfuly make this process work. A few comments. I first split the main dataframe using df_split = np.array_split(geodf, num_partitions) , where num_partitions =  number of cores I want to use. This is a process that takes up a lot of time and one needs to balance how many partitions to use wrt te time to process each partition. Other than that, the process became almost 1000x faster than iterating over rows.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to rolling your own parallel processing implementation, here's an simple example of using [dask](https://github.com/dask/dask) and [dask-geopandas](https://github.com/geopandas/dask-geopandas) to parallelize some polygon on raster statistics using the [rasterstats package](https://github.com/perrygeo/python-rasterstats).

To handle errors, you might want to look at iterating over successful ops as described in the [debug section of the dask documetation](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/how-to/debug.html#remove-failed-futures-manually).

```py
from dask.distributed import Client
import dask_geopandas as dgpd
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats
from rasterstats import zonal_stats


def kurtosis(arr):
    try:
        k = scipy.stats.kurtosis(arr.compressed())
    except AttributeError:  # Not a masked array - 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'compressed'
        k = scipy.stats.kurtosis(arr)
    return k


def zonal_statistics(row, *args, **kwargs):
    return row.join(pd.DataFrame(zonal_stats(gdf, *args, **kwargs), index=gdf.index))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = Client()

    zones = "zones.shp"
    values = "values.tif"

    # pre-defined stats, see the full list at
    # https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#zonal-statistics
    stats = ["mean", "std"]

    # user-defined stats 
    # https://pythonhosted.org/rasterstats/manual.html#user-defined-statistics
    add_stats = {"kurtosis": kurtosis}

    gdf = gpd.read_file(zones)
    ddf = dgpd.from_geopandas(gdf, npartitions=4)

    # we need to tell dask_geopandas what the output should look like
    meta = ddf._meta.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=stats+list(add_stats.keys())))

    res = ddf.map_partitions(zonal_statistics, meta=meta, raster=values, stats=stats, add_stats=add_stats, all_touched=True)

    results = res.compute()

    print(gdf.head())
    print(results.head())
```

Output:

```sh
   id                                           geometry
0   1  POLYGON ((440819.096 3751134.570, 440983.634 3...
1   2  POLYGON ((441147.373 3751255.178, 441265.585 3...
2   3  POLYGON ((441438.110 3751077.860, 441789.549 3...
3   4  POLYGON ((440808.713 3750651.340, 440925.327 3...
4   5  POLYGON ((441174.530 3750450.061, 441371.017 3...
   id                                           geometry  ...        std  kurtosis
0   1  POLYGON ((440819.096 3751134.570, 440983.634 3...  ...  16.546371 -0.129432
1   2  POLYGON ((441147.373 3751255.178, 441265.585 3...  ...   9.588606 -0.184888
2   3  POLYGON ((441438.110 3751077.860, 441789.549 3...  ...  18.036208  1.952527
3   4  POLYGON ((440808.713 3750651.340, 440925.327 3...  ...  12.462851 -0.581433
4   5  POLYGON ((441174.530 3750450.061, 441371.017 3...  ...  27.835329  0.251267
```

And here's an example of handling errors in the calculations:

```py
from dask.dataframe import from_delayed
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster, as_completed
import dask_geopandas as dgpd
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import scipy.stats
from rasterstats import zonal_stats


def kurtosis(arr):
    try:
        k = scipy.stats.kurtosis(arr.compressed())
    except AttributeError:  # Not a masked array - 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'compressed'
        k = scipy.stats.kurtosis(arr)
    return k


def zonal_statistics(row, *args, **kwargs):
    from random import randint
    if randint(0, 3) == 1:
        raise RuntimeError('Fake random error to test')

    gdf = row.compute()
    return gdf.join(pd.DataFrame(zonal_stats(gdf, *args, **kwargs), index=gdf.index))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    zones = "zones.shp"
    values = "values.tif"
    stats = ["mean", "std"]
    add_stats = {"kurtosis": kurtosis}

    cluster = LocalCluster()
    client = Client(cluster)

    gdf = gpd.read_file(zones)
    ddf = dgpd.from_geopandas(gdf, npartitions=4)

    # we need to tell dask_geopandas what the output should look like
    meta = ddf._meta.join(pd.DataFrame(columns=stats+list(add_stats.keys())))

    futures = [client.submit(zonal_statistics, p, raster=values, stats=stats, add_stats=add_stats, all_touched=True) for p in ddf.partitions]

    completed = []
    for future in as_completed(futures):
        try:
            data = future.result()
            completed.append(future)
        except Exception as exc:
            pass

    results = from_delayed(completed, meta=meta, verify_meta=False).compute()

    print(gdf.head())
    print(f"{len(gdf)} rows")
    print(results.head())
    print(f"{len(results)} rows")
```

Output:

```sh
2022-06-11 19:14:51,192 - distributed.worker - WARNING - Compute Failed
Key:       zonal_statistics-bddca01b8c33227011c65ea05a10f813
Function:  zonal_statistics
args:      (Dask GeoDataFrame Structure:
                  id  geometry
npartitions=1                 
6              int64  geometry
7                ...       ...
Dask Name: blocks, 5 tasks)
kwargs:    {'raster': 'values.tif', 'stats': ['mean', 'std'], 'add_stats': {'kurtosis': <function kurtosis at 0x7f5e4a7dbe50>}, 'all_touched': True}
Exception: "RuntimeError('Fake random error to test')"

   id                                           geometry
0   1  POLYGON ((440819.096 3751134.570, 440983.634 3...
1   2  POLYGON ((441147.373 3751255.178, 441265.585 3...
2   3  POLYGON ((441438.110 3751077.860, 441789.549 3...
3   4  POLYGON ((440808.713 3750651.340, 440925.327 3...
4   5  POLYGON ((441174.530 3750450.061, 441371.017 3...
8 rows
   id                                           geometry  ...        std  kurtosis
0   1  POLYGON ((440819.096 3751134.570, 440983.634 3...  ...  16.546371 -0.129432
1   2  POLYGON ((441147.373 3751255.178, 441265.585 3...  ...   9.588606 -0.184888
2   3  POLYGON ((441438.110 3751077.860, 441789.549 3...  ...  18.036208  1.952527
3   4  POLYGON ((440808.713 3750651.340, 440925.327 3...  ...  12.462851 -0.581433
4   5  POLYGON ((441174.530 3750450.061, 441371.017 3...  ...  27.835329  0.251267

6 rows
```